iOS Live Activity update from background
I'm trying to implement iOS Live Activity for Workout tracking application.
To simplify let's say: My Live Activity only contains Button to pause and resume workout, so it's title is "Pause" if workout is running and "Resume" if paused.
I utilize AppIntents to handle button press on Live Activity, pass the action (don't ask what way) to main application running in background (it plays sounds 3 seconds before exercise end, so it is definitely running), main application handles press and pauses/and resumes workout.
Sounds good yet...
In main application I need to update Live Activity to change button title to Resume / Pause.
I use Activity.update(_ content: ActivityContent<Activity.ContentState>) async
The problem is: UPDATE works in first several (up to ten) seconds after I send app into background (go to Lock Screen, where my Live Activity is located).
Button on Live Activity WORKS ALL THE TIME. But Activity.update stops doing anything.
Any ideas how I can force update Live Activity in response to user actions when app is in the background?
I see examples of apps in AppStore who manage to update Live Activity even in backgroud for long time.
I don't belive they do it via Remote Push Notifications (because it works even OffLine/Airplane mode).
Thank you.

You need to [edit] your question to show the relevant code.
